# Shrinking the root Linux partition from the left on dual boot: Will I be able to boot after?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows

I have a dual boot setup with Windows and Ubuntu, as seen in the image. My Windows basic data partition runs full, so I want to shrink the Linux ext4 / partition by moving it's left end to the right and then use the new space to extend the Windows partition to the right.
Will I lose grub in that process? It is installed in /boot/grub, but I guess only /boot/efi is on it's own partition, so grub is installed on the partition I want to shrink? Will I lose it, resulting in the system not being able to boot anymore?
Also, can I do it with a partitioning tool from within Windows or do I have to use an Ubuntu Live Stick?

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8Ud.png)

Comment: Backup everything on both operating systems, things can go badly wrong.  A left shrink is bad because it removes the beginning of the filesystem, making it unavailable, (yes, grub will be gone). You need to shrink from right (shrink fs first?), then move the partition right.

Comment: Okay, so if i shrink it from the right first and move it to the left after, grub will remain?

Comment: Careful, that will be a move right into the space you freed up by shrinking on the right. Grub's files will remain, but the filesystem's UUID may be changed since it has to shrink too.  This UUID change may need to be put into .../EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg, and /etc/fstab.  rerun update-grub should then pick up the new UUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'live' stick, as Windows Disk Manager will corrupt your EXT4 partition. And ubfan1 is right. Shrink it on the right side, then move it to the right. He is also right about the backups. 
I would try to enlarge your NTFS partition in Windows, if it would let you. If not do it with GParted. (has to be unmounted to do that.)