# What happens when one changes the sizes of partitions

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I understand how to use Gparted to change the sizes of partitions, eg to make /home smaller and / larger (I will move the lower boundary of /home to the right, and then move the upper boundary of / to the same point), but I would like to know what happens to the information initially stored in the space in the /home partition which becomes, thanks to Gparted, part of the / partition.  Does Gparted (hopefully) move the information to a "safe" part of /home before it repartitions the disk?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404746/shrinking-the-root-linux-partition-from-the-left-on-dual-boot-will-i-be-able-to  for method to avoid the shrink on left -- shrink on right then move partition right.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size of the partition doesn't actually do much with the data.  You have to change and/or copy the filesystem in the partition too.   Of course, gparted is nice enough to do this for you, so it is a bit pedantic to say that, but it helps to talk about shrinking and moving the filesystem separately from the partition boundaries.

So when you shrink the partition on the right, any files that were in that space have to be relocated to a lower position in the filesystem (if there were any), and then the freespace at the end of the filesystem can be truncated and the filesystem data structures adjusted to match, and the partition boundary moved.  This is generally pretty fast and safe.

When you move the left side of the partition, it has to copy all the data to a later part of the disk.  If the new and old locations overlap, it would copy the end of the filesystem first and then copy the previous section onto the old location of what it just copied...etc. until it has shifted the whole filesystem to the end of the partition, and then it can move the partition boundary.   Of course, this operation is very slow and very dangerous, in that all of the data must be copied, and if the disk fails or develops bad blocks or the copy is aborted part way through, you end up with a filesystem cut in half that isn't mountable with possibly corrupted data.